# C quiz program not understand

Tags: c++, c

Hello friends Anyone knowing why it is printing variable value Why it is not printing garbage value? it gives output 11 10 5

```
void main()
{
      int a=5,b=10,c=11;
      printf("%d %d %d");
      getch();
}
```

Comment: It's a stack underflow, phenomenon, shouln't compile (at least not without warning).

Comment: I am using turboc compiler it gives 3 warning like a , b,c  value assigned but never used but program gives an output

Comment: Don't use Turbo-C++, it's ancient and crappy.

Comment: "quiz program"? Where?

Comment: It's a trick question. The quiz wants you to point out the error in `void main` (or so I'd hope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behaviour.

According to the C Standard

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined

For example running your function at www.ideone.com I get the following result

```
-1081083132 -1081083124 -1219330483
```

So it seems that your compiler generated the object code such a way that the local variables in main were adjusted by chance such a way that they fit the stack of printf.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing garbage. The fact is that your garbage contains the values 5,10 and 11, thats why they are being printed. Try to execute this code somewhere else, or in your own machine after some clean up.

Here, ive got 0, 10032928, 4199093 as output.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your printf statement to:

```
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c)
```

The first argument to the printf command is called the format string and it tells the run-time how you want things printed.  In you case, you are stating that you want to print three integers separated by a single space.  However in your original program you didn't tell the run time **what** values to print.

You can think of things starting with a % (like %d, %c or %f) as placeholders that will be filled in by the arguments that come after the format string.  There are some exceptions to this, but for now it should serve you well.

There are two things to remember here;

1. if there are 5 placeholders in the format string, you need to provide five additional arguments to printf representing the data to substitute for those place holders.  This is what 'Vlad from Moscow' was showing from the C-standard.
2. Encoded in the placeholder is the type of data that is being expected; *i.e.*
   `%c` is the placeholder for a character, and passing it a float is going to produce both compiler diagnostics as well as unusual behaviour when run.

You can find much, much more about [format strings here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)